# standardized international phone number field format as a string

Tags: internationalization, phone-number

I'd like to store phone numbers as unique user ids in my database/app which will initially roll out in the United States but could expand to other countries eventually.

My question is when storing phone numbers, what's a resilient way to store the number as a string so that I don't have any duplicate numbers from other countries overlap.

My initial thought is to do it this way

```
+1(212)555-5555

+{countryCode}({areaCode}){{subscriberCode}}  *formatted with a hyphen for u.s numbers
```

Does that seem reasonable or are there any pitfalls to that?  Should spaces be used?  For instance I can't imagine other countries would use spaces or parenthesis in their subscriber codes... but maybe they do?  It would also be nice if it followed the standard output format from ios and android phones' address books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like there is an international standard

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

And a node.js library that can format to that standard

https://github.com/aftership/node-phone

Comment: notice that node-phone is only for mobile phone detection, the goal to create that lib is for detect the mobile phone number in order to send out the SMS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd say:

- Use the plus. It indicates for certain that the country code follows and the number is not in a local format. You could also not store the plus and make an internal decision that all phone numbers will be stored with the country code, thus obviating the need for the plus.
- Don't use any formatting in the storage of the number. Formatting is irrelevant when it comes to dialing and it makes searching and comparing more difficult.
- Use a gem like [phony_rails](https://github.com/joost/phony_rails) or [phoney](https://github.com/habermann24/phoney) to format the number to local conventions when displaying.

Comment: I ended up keeping the paranthesis because it comes natively from ios that way and I didn't have to change the format